# Is there a general way of finding the value of a continued fraction whose terms form a geometric sequence?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, continued-fractions

So something like $$\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{4}{8+\cfrac{16}{32+\cfrac{64}{\ddots}}}}.$$

Comment: "*whose terms are a part of a geometric sequence*"  I think you mean *arithmetic* sequence here.  A geometric sequence is something like $1,2,4,8,16,32,64,\dots$

Comment: My other question isn't related to the first one in that regard. What I mean is that is there a general way of finding the value of a continued fraction whose terms are geometric like (1/(2+4/(8+16/(32+64/(....)?

Comment: I suggest you [edit] the title then.

Comment: sure, thank you!

Comment: Of interest on the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=6%2C9%2C1%2C5%2C9%2C4%2C1&sort=&language=english&go=Search).

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat more generally, note that
$$\eqalign{ 1 + \dfrac{r}{r^2 + \dfrac{r^3}{r^4 + r^5/(r^6+\ldots)}}
&= 1 + \dfrac{1}{r + \dfrac{r^2}{r^4+r^5/(r^6+\ldots)}}\cr &=
1 + \dfrac{1}{r + \dfrac{1}{r^2 + r^3/(r^6+\ldots)}}\cr
&= 1 + \dfrac{1}{r + \dfrac{1}{r^2 +
1/(r^3+\ldots)}}}$$

The convergents of the continued fraction
$1+1/(2+1/(4+1/(8+1/(16+\ldots$ are 
$n(i)/d(i)$ where $n$ and $d$ are OEIS sequences [A061377](https://oeis.org/A061377)
and [A015473](https://oeis.org/A015473) respectively.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: the question title changed, making some of this irrelevant.)

Here is the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) on a "continued" fraction (not "continuous").

The article says that $$1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{4+\cdots}}}$$ is equal to $\frac{I_0(2)}{I_1(2)}$ where $I_n(x)$ is a type of [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

The article gives another example of an *arithemetic* sequence continued fraction:
$$\tanh(1/n)=\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{3n+\frac{1}{5n+\frac{1}{7n+\cdots}}}}$$

I don't see an example of a geometric sequence continued fraction, and it seems like if something was known about such a thing, even one example, it would be reported here.